# Stochastic Differential Equation- When martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Suppose I'd like to check the martingale property for some SDE. What do I have to require for it to be martingale? I know that no drift is one requirement, but what are the others?

Comment: @ SSE : Well sde's with null drift are local martingales, so your question is really about conditions that ensures that a sde's are real martingales you should google this first. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge I can't find it, that's why I ask it here. Maybe you can give me a url?

Comment: @ SSE : You could start here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/criteria-for-being-a-true-martingale/38947#38947

Comment: @TheBridge Can I not ''by inspection'' conclude from an SDE whether it is a martingale?