# When is an SDE a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

**Here's the question:**

Let $X(t)$ be a stochastic process such that

$$ dX = a(t)Xdt + b(t)XdW(t) $$

where $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted processes with "good" properties. Furthermore $b(t)$ is non-zero almost surely. $W(t)$ is a wiener process with respect to a measure $P$. For which $a(t)$ is $X(t)$ a $P$-martingale?

**My attempt:**

A martingale cannot have a drift term so it must be of the form $dX = v(t,X)dW(t)$ for some $v$. Therefore $a(t) \equiv 0$.

**This was incorrect, but no feedback was given as to why this is not right**. Could anyone point out the mistake and/or give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: When the drift is null you can only say that it is a local "martingale", so null dirft is necessary but not sufficient for it to be a true martingale you can check this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/criteria-for-being-a-true-martingale/38947#38947

Answer (score 3):

You only find one solution but not a general one.

Let $Y$ be a stochastic process such that $$dY = b(t)dW(t) + \left(a(t) - \frac{1}{2}b^2(t)\right) dt$$ 
Then $$X(t) = e^{Y(t)}$$ is a solution to your SDE. Additionally we know that $X(t)$ is a so called exponential martingale iff $$Y(t) = M_t - \frac{1}{2}<M>_t$$ for a martingale $M$.

But we have: $$Y(t) = \int_0^t b(u) dW(u) + \int_0^t \left(a(u) - \frac{1}{2}b^2(u)\right) dt$$ so our candidate for $M$ is: $$M_t = \int_0^t b(u) dW(u)$$

What's now $\frac{1}{2}<M>_t$ and which condition is necessary for $a$ that it holds $$\frac{1}{2}<M>_t =  \int_0^t \left(\frac{1}{2}b^2(u) - a(u)\right) dt$$ because for all those $a$ your process $X$ is a martingale.